# gzip_b64encode reintroducing backslashes that were removed with json.dumps separator operator

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an api gateway with lambda proxy integration and I have enabled gzip_b64encode to compress the payload (pulled from S3) on the lambda side. Prior to adding that, my output did not have backslashes, but after doing this, they are again there.
here is what the output looks like:

```
[{\"Exchange\":\"TSE\",\"Ticker\":1301,\"Name\":\"Kyokuyo\",\"Country\":\"Japan\",\"Currency\":\"JPY\",\"Asset_Type\":\"Common Stock\",\"ISIN\":\"JP3257200000\",\"Date\":\"4/30/2023\",\"Open\":3580.0,\"High\":3590.0,\"Low\":3545.0,\"Close\":3560.0,\"Volume\":20800,
```

here is my code:

```
import json
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import gzip
import awswrangler as wr
import boto3

def gzip_b64encode(data):
    compressed = BytesIO()
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed, mode='w') as f:
        json_response = json.dumps(data)
        f.write(json_response.encode('utf-8'))
    return base64.b64encode(compressed.getvalue()).decode('ascii')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(event)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket_name = 'tse-candles'
    
    format = event['queryStringParameters']['fmt']
    day = event['queryStringParameters']['date']
    
    A = '123.csv'
    full_path = f"s3://{bucket_name}"

    if day == 'today':
     
      raw_df = wr.s3.read_csv(path=f'{full_path}/{A}', use_threads=True)
      
      if format == 'json':
        
        df = raw_df.to_json(orient="records")
        parsed = json.loads(df)
        parsed_w_separators = json.dumps(parsed, separators=(',', ':'))
      
        return {
          "isBase64Encoded": True,
          "statusCode": 200,
          "headers": { 
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
            },
          'body': gzip_b64encode(parsed_w_separators)
          }
```

Can someone tell me if the the gzip encoding is causing this, and how to correct?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving the json.dumps separators up to the top part where the gzip encoding was being defined. I also added the indent=4 there and it made my output perfect.

```
def gzip_b64encode(data):
    compressed = BytesIO()
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed, mode='w') as f:
        json_response = json.dumps(data, indent=4, separators=(',', ':'))
        f.write(json_response.encode('utf-8'))
    return base64.b64encode(compressed.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
```

I also commented the reference down lower in the script and am encoding the dataframe that was already properly formatted at the top.

```
df = raw_df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed = json.loads(df)
#parsed_w_separators = json.dumps(parsed, separators=(',', ':'))
#parsed_w_separators = json.dumps(parsed, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ':'))

return {
  "isBase64Encoded": True,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": { 
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
    },
  'body': gzip_b64encode(parsed)
  }
```